# Combining four distinct objects with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> With four different objects $k = \{obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4\}$. How many **combinations** are there if I were to copy $20$ freely-chosen objects. I could for example have $20\times obj1$ if I wanted.
>
> However, permutations are not to be counted.

#### Probable solution

I'm thinking I need to use one of the following (*theorems?)*: $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}\quad or\quad \binom{n+k-1}{n}$$ However, there are two problems with this. I wouldn't know which one, and I can't find any understandable explanation. The latter I withdrew from the theorem from *stars and bars* method.

What's the difference betweeen the formulas? And should I even use one of these formulas for my problem?

The first yields $8855$ combinations, and the second yields $1771$ combinations.

#### Further question

Wherever I look, people use the formulas interchangeably$^{[1]}$, however; they're not equal. Take for example: $$\binom{9+3-1}{3} \not= \binom{9+3-1}{9}$$

How come?

$^{[1]}$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two_2

Comment: Let $x_1$ be the number of instances of object $1$ that we will use, $x_2$ the number of instances of object $2$, and so on. Then we want to find the number of solutions of the equation
$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=20$ 
in non-negative integers. This is a canonical Stars and Bars problem.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't know which formula would be the right one and why. My book gave me the first one, and the second one was taken from the Wikipedia entry on Stars and Bars.

Comment: Let $n=20$ and $k=4$. Then the number is $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$, or equivalently $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. The explanation in Wikipedia is pretty good. I hesitate to write out an answer, because the problem has been dealt with on MSE many times. Note that the answer is $1771$. I do not see how you got $1771$ out of $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Comment: I added a question in the bodytext, as the question could be interpreted as a duplicate of many other questions on MSE.

Comment: "Wherever I look, people use the formulas interchangeably" Really? I find that very interesting and I'd love to see an example of that.

Comment: Added source on my claim.

Comment: @XMLParsing Well, one of those is "n multichoose k" and the other is "k multichoose n", so it is not surprising that the formulas are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$ in non-negative integers is
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\quad\text{or alternately}\quad\binom{n+k-1}{n}.$$

In your **further question**, it looks as if you are using $n=9$ and $k=3$. Then the first version should be $\binom{9+3-1}{3-1}$, not $\binom{9+3-1}{3}$.

In the original question, we want to find the number of solutions in non-negative integers of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=20.$$
By standard Stars and Bars, the number is $\binom{20+4-1}{4-1}$, or equivalently $\binom{20+4-1}{20}$.

**Remark:** The equivalence of the two versions follows from the fact that in general $\binom{m}{r}=\binom{m}{m-r}$.

Comment: I see you're using the formula from the Stars and Bars method. However, take a look at the sources I've linked in my body text, why is Wolfram refering to a formula where $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$? Would be real nice if you could shed some light on this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: In the Wolfram version, the roles of $n$ and $k$ are interchanged, they are solving $x_1+\cdots +x_n=k$. Good reason not to memorize formulas! I actually kind of figure it out from scratch each time, because my memory for formulas, though not terrible, is definitely not good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the cases down by the number of distinct objects in your set of $20$.

If you have (exactly) one distinct object, there are $4$ combinations (twenty of **obj1, obj2, obj3,** or **obj4**).

If you have (exactly) two distinct objects, you can divide them up $(19, 1), (18, 2), (17, 3), ... (10, 10)$.  Let's first look at the case $(x,y)$ where $10 < x < 20$.  You choose the object $x$, then the different object $y$.  There are $12$ ways to do this, and $9$ values of $x$, so there are $108$ combinations.  For $x=y=10$, there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ combinations.  So, the number of combinations for two distinct types of objects is $108+6=114$.

I'd build up the cases for three and four distinct objects in a similar way.